# How to display graphics in IOS when connected remotely with Linux server?

Tags: mac, linux, gui, grass.script, grass-7.8

I am trying to work using GRASS GIS for my data remotely from Mac. Here is what I have done:

1. XQuartz was installed and run;
2. Terminal was run. I typed: `ssh -Y root@IPaddress`
3. Then I typed: `grass64` (to be able to use grass commands in terminal)
4. Afterwards got a question about directory to chose and the information:

> ```
> WARNING: It appears that the X Windows system is not active.
> A graphical based user interface is not supported.
> Switching to text based interface mode.
> ```

I am struggling with enabling window to display rasters that I have. I tried to type -X despite -Y, as well running GRASS before, but nothing works.. My GRASS version is 7.8.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Tip for today: Always restart your computer before asking for help.